# Firebase: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 code: 13,
  details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
```

This error happens to me with the emulator on every attempt, so may be an easy case to reproduce

Under Node.js /sveltekit server endpoint. Here are my lib versions:

```
pnpm view firebase-admin dependencies

{
  '@fastify/busboy': '^1.1.0',
  '@firebase/database-compat': '^0.3.0',
  '@firebase/database-types': '^0.10.0',
  '@types/node': '>=12.12.47',
  jsonwebtoken: '^9.0.0',
  'jwks-rsa': '^3.0.1',
  'node-forge': '^1.3.1',
  uuid: '^9.0.0',
  '@google-cloud/firestore': '^6.4.0',
  '@google-cloud/storage': '^6.5.2'
}
```

My use case is pretty simple:
**firebaseInit.js:**

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
const useEmulator = true;

if (useEmulator){
    process.env['FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST'] = 'localhost:4000';
}

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "linkedincv-bdbec.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "linkedincv-bdbec",
    storageBucket: "linkedincv-bdbec.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const db = getFirestore(app);

const db = admin.firestore();

export {app, db}
```

My code using the initialized db variable:

**+server.js**

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import {db} from '../../../lib/middleware/firebaseInit'

export async function POST({request}) {
    try {
        const payload = await request.json();
        const uniqueUrl = payload.uniqueUrl;

        const docRef = await db.collection("json_cv").doc("zied").set( payload)
        // Return the document ID of the stored object
        return json({
            body: JSON.stringify({ documentId: docRef.id }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 200
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during processing
        console.error(error);
        return json({
            body: JSON.stringify({ error }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 500
        });
    }
}
```

Just to be complete if you want to reproduce, here's a file specific to sveltekit allowing CORS
**hooks.server.js**

```
import { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle = async ({ resolve, event }) => {
    const response = await resolve(event);

    // Apply CORS header for API routes
    if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/cv/submit')) {
        // Required for CORS to work
        if(event.request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            return new Response(null, {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                }
            });
        }

        response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', `*`);
    }

    return response;
};
```

**Note:** I saw there was a [bug talking about this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1023) issue, but it doesn't seem to be systematic for them

Comment: Possibly related to the Firebase emulator setup or compatibility between the Firebase SDK version and other dependencies. You may file a bug in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com) so that the Product team will check on this, However there's no ETA for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running **firebase init** a second time, things solved. It might be that as I'm a newbie in firebase, I didn't run the initialization with the right parameters the first time. But as I was discovering things, I couldn't remind what I did wrong.